# How to move appended rows up or down using jQuery

Tags: jquery

So basically if rows already exists in DOM them moving rows up and down works perfectly but rows append rows using jquery and try to move up and down it doesn't work.

```js
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
 count=$('table tr').length;
 var data="<tr><td>"+count+"</td>";
      data+="<td><a class='down' href='#'>Down</a> <a class='up' href='#'>Up</a></td>";
  $('table').append(data);
});


$(".up,.down").click(function () {
  var $element = this;
  var row = $($element).parents("tr:first");
  if($(this).is('.up')){
     row.insertBefore(row.prev());
  }
  else{
      row.insertAfter(row.next());
  }
       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add Row</button>
      
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>           
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
      <td><a class="down" href="#">Down</a> <a class="up" href="#">UP</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please run the above example as it will clearly explain.

**In this example you can see Row ID 1 is moving up and down perfectly as it already exists in the table but if I add more rows it then moving them doesn't work.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the following it works with even newly added elements.

```
$("table").on("click",".up,.down", function {});
```

```js
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
 count=$('table tr').length;
 var data="<tr><td>"+count+"</td>";
      data+="<td><a class='down' href='#'>Down</a> <a class='up' href='#'>Up</a></td>";
  $('table').append(data);
});


$("table").on("click",".up,.down", function () {
  var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
  if($(this).is('.up')){
    row.insertBefore(row.prev());
  }
  else{
    row.insertAfter(row.next());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add Row</button>
      
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>           
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
      <td><a class="down" href="#">Down</a> <a class="up" href="#">UP</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow Simple stuff I got mad trying so many things. Thanks its works. :)

Comment: what is wrong with `$(".up,.down").click(function () {`

Comment: The issue is $(".up,.down") is generating the jQuery object and then assigning a click value to it, on load.  However, we want to select our table and then all elements underneath that we will filter for .up and .down, that way we can accommodate new elements.